# Sharepoint Online - Modern Experience - Multi-Select People Picker - Is there a way to ensure the input sort order is retained?

Tags: sharepoint-online, multi-select, peoplepicker

Sharepoint Online - Modern Experience - Multi-Select People Picker - Is there a way to ensure the input sort order is retained?

I want to add a multi-select people picker to allow input of a list of sequential approvers. For example, I want to add Joe, Jane, Mary, Fred, Yi as my approvers. I'll build power automate flows to send approvals to Joe first. Then, if Joe approves, I'll send an approval to Jane, and so on.

In Sharepoint 2013, this seemed to work and if I input Joe, Jane, Mary Fred, and Yi, it retained that sort order in the multi-choice people picker field. Then, I could use automation to process the approvals in the correct sequence.

In Sharepoint online modern experience, when I input Joe, Jane, Mary, Fred, and Yi, it seems to sort them by some internal ID and does NOT retain the original sort order. Maybe Sharepoint Online sorts it as Yi, Jane, Mary, Fred, Joe based on some internal ID (I cannot see this internal ID or reference it in power automate).  This messes me up because now the names are not in the proper approval sequence.

Is there some way to force Sharepoint Online Modern to retain the input sort order of a multi-choice people picker?

I really don't prefer to have fields - approver1, approver2, approver3, etc.

I prefer to have the approvers in one multi-choice people picker and use that.

In Sharepoint online modern experience, when I input Joe, Jane, Mary, Fred, and Yi, it seems to sort them by some internal ID and does NOT retain the original sort order. Maybe Sharepoint Online sorts it as Yi, Jane, Mary, Fred, Joe based on some internal ID (I cannot see this internal ID or reference it in power automate).  This messes me up because now the names are not in the proper approval sequence.

I've tried this with a customized form, the generic form, etc. It actually responds inconsistently. Sometimes, it looks like Sharepoint Online retains the sort order. Other times, it re-sorts it. This could even vary by person. Some persons experience retaining the sort order, others it re-sorts.

I need a way to ensure the input sort order is retained.